# Package tracking app that supports forwarding emails containing tracking numbers

Tags: email

I'm looking for a package tracking app that supports forwarding emails with tracking numbers in them to a specified email address to add them to the list of tracked packages.

It would be nice if it were possible to add package information via the web **and** my mobile device, but I'll settle for one or the other.

Comment: There are so many possible interpretations of your questions possible, I can't enumerate them here.. Please be very specific, on what you are searching for, what is the background etc.!